# How to vote for a close on an old question that is no longer on topic

Tags: discussion

I came accross the question [Demonstrable and repeatable examples of evolution](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2057/demonstrable-and-repeatable-examples-of-evolution) which is an old question, it may have been on topic when it was posted, but now it is no longer on topic, what is the correct closure reason for such questions?

Just for clarification I think that that the question should remain on the site, but as a closed "heritage" question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be “locked” (rather than “closes”) as having “Historical significance”. The difference is that a locked question, in addition to not accepting answers, also cannot be voted on or edited.

I think that would be the most appropriate here. Thoughts?

Comment: I support that.